# Getting error 500 when trying to obtain access token from authorization code

Tags: google-oauth

Before this question gets closed as too specific I quote from the official [Google OAuth Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/oauth2-dev):

> As of March 4, 2013, discussion on this group has move to google-oauth
>   tag on Stack Overflow
>
> We support the Google OAuth2 on Stack Overflow. Google engineers
>   monitor and answer against the tag google-oauth. You should use this
>   tag when asking questions.

Starting this morning (2014-07-18) some of my users are getting error 500 Internal Server error with payload `{ "error" : "internal_failure" }` when trying to obtain an access token using a previously obtained authorization code from Google's token endpoint: `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token`.

Hopefully some Google engineer monitoring the `google-oauth` tag here would be able to provide more insight.

Comment: Same problem - did you found a fix? I am starting a bounty an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

500 Internal Server error is a hiccup on googles side or flood protection.   Its normally resolved by sending the same request again while implementing  [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreErrors#backoff).

I find it strange that the request was from the Oauth servers which would make me think maybe the servers were down at the time.  Resending the request should solve the problem.

> Handling 500 or 503 responses
>
> A 500 or 503 error might result during heavy load or for larger more
>   complex requests. For larger requests consider requesting data for a
>   shorter time period. Also consider implementing exponential backoff.
>   The frequency of these errors can be dependent on the view (profile)
>   and the amount of reporting data associated with that view; A query
>   that causes a 500 or 503 error for one view (profile) will not
>   necessarily cause an error for the same query with a different view
>   (profile).